# Cant access Postgres, getting an error about “/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432”

Tags: postgresql

I was running a Django application with Postgres as backend database. It was working fine. All of a sudden, today I saw my database connection is refusing in the production server. So I logged into my server and tried to:

```
psql
```

and then it was showing this error:

```
 psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The file listed above does not seem to exist.

I checked if my Postgres is running or not with:

```
 /etc/init.d/postgresql status
```

and it was returning with SUCCESS message.

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-11-16 10:03:41 UTC; 55min ago
  Process: 4701 ExecReload=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4899 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4899 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 16 10:03:41 median systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Nov 16 10:03:41 median systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Still, I stopped and started `postgres` again.

I checked if there any other `postgres` task running or not with:

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

And it returned:

```
root      5210  5117  0 10:21 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

So there is no other Postgres.

I even checked if my Postgres accidentally got deleted or not with

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

and it returned

```
ii  postgresql                           9.5+173ubuntu0.1                             all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-9.5                       9.5.10-0ubuntu0.16.04                        amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.5 server
ii  postgresql-client-9.5                9.5.10-0ubuntu0.16.04                        amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.5
ii  postgresql-client-common             173ubuntu0.1                                 all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                    173ubuntu0.1                                 all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib-9.5               9.5.10-0ubuntu0.16.04                        amd64        additional facilities for PostgreSQL
```

So there is no `rc` instead of `ii`, which means it has not been uninstalled.

I have tried every other solution in the internet but uninstalling Postgres. Didn't work for me. I might be doing something very silly. I don't want to uninstall and lose my data.

Comment: Can you do `grep "PGPORT" /etc/init.d/postgresql` and show us the output?

Comment: it returns blank

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to check which port your PostgreSQL server is actually running on:

```
[root@server ~]# netstat -a | grep .s.PGSQL
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2534417 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I can see from this output that my server is listening on port 5432 and also that the file is created in `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

You can then update `/etc/init.d/postgresql` to include the lines

```
PGPORT=5432
export PGPORT
```

and update your `postgresql.conf` file which is located in your data directory and set the port key/value to `port=5432`

and then restart your PostgreSQL server

```
[root@server] service postgresql restart
```

Comment: I checked which port the postgres is running on with 

    `netstat -a | grep .s.PGSQL`
it showed nothing

Comment: What's the output of `service postgresql status` ? Does it return `postmaster (pid  11288) is running...`? Also you can retry `netstat -a | grep post` instead

Comment: Can you check your configurations/LSB file for the `PGPORT`/`port` key/values?

Comment: it returns nothing. when I tried to check the status with ` /etc/init.d/postgresql status` it return success

Comment: What do you mean success? The return code is 0? Is anything printed out? Have you debugged this script to see what part of the LSB is getting executed before it returns success?

Comment: Grep your files for the words.. or vim them and use / to search